# Finding rate of convergence of sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, rate-of-convergence

Let $\alpha_n$ be sequence that converges to $\alpha$. I'd like to find such numbers $c, d$ that $\alpha_n - \alpha \approx cn^-d$.

I've found a solution to a similar problem - finding the order of convergence. I'd like to modify it to find the rate instead. Let's take a formula to approximate the order: $ d \approx \frac{ \ln | (\alpha_{n+1} - \alpha_n) / (\alpha_n - \alpha_{n-1})| } { \ln | (\alpha_n - \alpha_{n-1}) / (\alpha_{n - 1} - \alpha_{n-2}) | } $.

It is derived from $|\alpha_n - \alpha| \approx c|\alpha_{n-1} - \alpha|^d$

Since I have $|\alpha_n - \alpha| \approx cn^d$, the formula for the rate would be (if I'm not mistaken): $d \approx \frac{\ln |(\alpha_{n + 1} - \alpha_n) / (\alpha_n - \alpha_{n - 1})|}{\ln ((n + 1) / n)}$.

I tried testing it on some examples, but it seems like either I had made a mistake in the formula or it's not very accurate. Suprisingly (at least for me), $d$ calculated using the first formula for the order was almost perfect. Am I doing something wrong?

Edit: I've checked that after putting the value of $\alpha$ in the formula ($d \approx \frac{ln|(\alpha_{n+1} - \alpha)/(\alpha_n - \alpha)}{ln((n+1)/n)}$) it works pretty well. I assume then the problem lies here. Is there any other way to get rid of $\alpha$ value?

Comment: Nothing particular, any convergent sequence. I'm testing it on Euler's constant and a sequence $\alpha_n = H_n - ln(n)$

Comment: http://www.math-cs.gordon.edu/courses/ma342/handouts/rate.pdf link to the first formula. I'm basically trying to achieve big O of error $\epsilon = \alpha_n - \alpha$. Of course, assumption that $\alpha_n - \alpha \approx cn^d$ may be wrong, but even if the sequence does converge lineary (like the one I've mentioned) that formula fails.

Comment: Well, I did manage to find those constants, $d$ is about -1, and $c$ about 0,5, but that's not the point. I'd like to find a formula that will let me find $d$ constant given any sequence $\alpha_n$ that converges to some constant $\alpha$ (unknown by me) assuming that $\alpha_n - \alpha \approx cn^d$.

Comment: Yes, if I find the exponent $d$ it is trivial to calculate the value of $c$.

Comment: Are you sure there aren't supposed to be log in the denominator? I mean... $\frac{\alpha_{n+1} - \alpha}{\alpha_n - \alpha} \approx (\frac{n+1}{n})^d$. And still, as I said, I do not know the value of $\alpha$, it should not be used in the final formula.

Comment: You are aware that it is exactly the same formula I've written, right?

Comment: Ah ok , I see now it is asymptotically equivalent.

Comment: If $d$ is supposed to be a rate of *convergence*, then you should change that to $cn^{-d}$

Comment: Yes, I've made a typo, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Let $b_n = cn^d$, then $$\frac {b_{n+1}}{b_n} = \left(1 + \frac 1n\right)^d = 1 + d\frac 1n + \frac {d(d-1)}2\left(\frac 1n\right)^2 + ...$$

and so $$d = \lim_n n\left(\frac {b_{n+1}}{b_n} - 1\right)$$

Translating to $\alpha_n$, this becomes
$$d = \lim_n n\left(\frac {\alpha_{n+1}-\alpha}{\alpha_n - \alpha} - 1\right)=\lim_n n\left(\frac {\alpha_{n+1}-\alpha_n}{\alpha_n - \alpha}\right)$$

Of course, once you have $d$, $c$ is just $$c = \lim_n\frac{\alpha_n - \alpha}{n^d}$$

Comment: Is it possible to approximate $\alpha$ by a different value? I'd like to avoid using this constant, since it is not always known.

Comment: You are taking two limits here already. Why are you shying from taking a third? You cannot just replace $\alpha$ with $\alpha_{n+k}$ for some fixed $k$. If you do, the limit will be $1/k$ instead of $d$. You could substitute $\alpha_m$ for $\alpha$, and make it a double limit in $m,n$. But that is just disguising taking the third limit instead of avoiding it.